# How to save two lists with Unicode strings in csv file in Python?

Tags: python, list, csv, unicode, arabic

I have a list of lists which contains Arabic words. I split this list into two lists and I am trying to save them into separate columns in a CSV file:

```
import csv   
words = ['يعمل','في','جامعة']
tags = ['verb','prep','noun']
with open('results.csv','w', encoding = 'utf-16') as outfile:
    rowlists = zip(words, tags)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row in rowlists:
        writer.writerows(row)
```

The code above ouputs the following:

[image: csv_ouput1]

Things get slightly better if I replace the for loop with `writer.writerows(rowlists)`:

[image]

But still, all is lumped together in one column. The same code works fine if the first list is in English (after removing the encoding). I suspect the zip function is having trouble with Unicode, but I am not sure. Any ideas on how to get this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your `writer.writerows` to `writer.writerow`

```
# coding=utf-8
import csv
words = ['يعمل','في','جامعة']
tags = ['verb','prep','noun']
with open('results.csv', 'w', encoding = 'utf-16', newline='') as outfile:
    rowlists = zip(words, tags)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row in rowlists:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Thanks Vikas. That still doesn't solve it. It lumps everything in one column (similar to the second screenshot).

Comment: But with this code the output on my machine is split in two columns, with first column the English words and second column containing the Arabic words. -------> يعمل,verb
في,prep
جامعة,noun

Comment: Very interesting. Not on my machine. I am using Windows 7, 64 bit, and I am opening the CSV with Excel 2013. I am coding with Spyder 2.3.52, and using Python version 3.4.3. What could be the problem?!

Comment: Dont open it with excel. That is the problem. Excel has problems opening unicode charactered csv files. If you want to open it in Excel, open a blank workbook and use Data menu to import data.

Comment: Indeed. I was able to import into Excel, so it seems Excel is having trouble with opening Unicode characters. What other program do you use to open CSV files?

Comment: Notepad++ or Sublime Text

Answer (score 2):

The main problem in this case is not the encoding of text but what is being passed in the `writer.writerows` function.
zip() function return a list of tuples. `writerows` function splits text in different columns when a list is provided.

So instead of passing a **tuple** pass a **list**.

```
# coding=utf-8
import csv   
words = ['يعمل','في','جامعة']
tags = ['verb','prep','noun']
with open('results.csv','w') as outfile:
    rowlists = zip(words, tags)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row in rowlists:
        writer.writerows([row])
```

Comment: Thanks Izhar for the input. It seems `writerows()` is working with both **tuples** and **lists**. As Vikas showed above, using `writerow()` rather than `writerows()` fixed the problem. Seeing the output in columns was an Excel issue, not a Python issue. The question would be if the results are the same, what would be the advantage of using **lists** over **tuples** with `writerows()`?

Comment: `writerow()` is used to write a single row in csv whereas `writerows()` is used to write multiple row at once. The syntax of `writerows()` requires a **list** of row obects, so when you were passing a tuple in `writerows()` each character was written in a different column in csv file.